# Having some real difficulties with absoloute positioning & responsive design

Tags: css

I am working on a site which requires responsive design. The desktop version I have built is perfectly ok and works nicely on all res. However, when it comes to mobiles & tablets I running into issues with my absolute positioning on images. I have swapped the px to % which works to an extent but become ugly if on a 27"imac like me!

Some css:

```
img.redpin{
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-480px;
    z-index: 999999;
}

img.yellowpin{
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:-400px;
    z-index: 999999;
}

img.greenpin{
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    z-index: 999999;
}


img.carrot{
    position:absoloute;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 222222;
    transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
height: 240px;
    max-width: 100%;    
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 220px;
    border: solid 5px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #2d2d2d;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #2d2d2d; 
}
img.potatos{
    position:absoloute;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 333333;
    transform:rotate(6deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(6deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(6deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    max-width: 100%;    
    max-height: 100%;   
    height: 240px;
    width: 220px;
    border: solid 5px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #2d2d2d;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #2d2d2d; 
}
img.garden{
    position:absoloute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 444444;
    transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    height: 240px;
    width: 220px;
    border: solid 5px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #2d2d2d;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #2d2d2d; 
    }
img.sticky{
    position:absoloute;
    margin-top: -110px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 555555;
    transform:rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(3deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    height: 199px;
    width: 280px;
}
```

The above all sit in a div which is the following:

```
#mainpagetop{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/themes/GYO/images/topdivbg.png);
    height: 330px;
    max-width : 920px; width: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Ok so the mainpagetop div scales perfectly but the inside aren't so great, I need them to scale down in size and preferably drop one of the image if viewed on a mobile.

Comment: Would you mind sending me your html so I can more closely see what the problem is. Are there any divs nested inside of #mainpagetop, or is it only the images that are referenced in your css?

Comment: Would media queries not help?

Comment: I can certaintly send you the code - what are your details? Skype?